# uWSGI worker free, but request' handling has significant delay

Tags: uwsgi, web-worker

I would like to run Django app under uWSGI behind nginx. I've launched 2 uwsgi workers, but I noticed next sad circumstance: when one worker is busy, another worker starts handle request only after 10-15 seconds of waiting.

Configuration is pretty simple.

uWSGI:

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --wsgi-file wsgi.py --master --processes 2 --threads 1
```

nginx:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name example.org;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
    }
}
```

and /etc/nginx/nginx.conf - default value

test Django view:

```
def test(request):
    print('Start!!!')
    time.sleep(9999)
    print('End')
    return HttpResponse()
```

And wsgi.py has default Django value.

So when I launch all this together and send 2 GET requests then I see in console only one "Start!!!" and only after 10-15 seconds apears second "Start!!!".

I have the same strange behaviour without nginx (with uwsgi --http); with multiple threads for each worker; without "--master" uwsgi option; without django app; with a few uwsgi instances behind Nginx load balancer.

Additional info:

uwsgi version: 2.0.12

nginx version: 1.4.6

host OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Python version: 3.4

Django: 1.9

CPU: 4 cores

Comment: Are you testing first and second request from starting uWSGI server? If yes, what about next requests? When server was working for a while and had processed some requests, will there still be an 10-15 seconds lag?

Comment: 1. I sent requests via browser.
2. Next requests not been processed, because I launched uwsgi with only 2 workers.
3. After a few hours of work server still had 10-15 seconds delay.